# Dynamic object field as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I'm wondering why I can't pass the fields of a dynamic object directly to a method that takes the same type of argument.

Here's the method signature:

```
public static void LoadPhotoFromS3(string incomingS3Region, string incomingS3Bucket, string incomingS3Key, LogObject logFormatter)
```

And here's the invocation using fields from an object declared 'dynamic':

```
dynamic s3UploadMessage = JObject.Parse(s3MessageText);
dynamic uploadedFileInfo = s3UploadMessage.Records[0];
var s3Region = uploadedFileInfo.awsRegion;
var s3Bucket = uploadedFileInfo.s3.bucket.name;
PhotoUtils.LoadPhotoFromS3(s3Region, s3Bucket, s3Key, logFormatter);
```

Problem is when I call it this way I get the compilation error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'AP.ePixNextGen.Utils.PhotoUtils.LoadPhotoFromS3(string, string, string, AP.LogUtilities.LogObject)' has some invalid arguments

If I do the following the method call works:

```
PhotoUtils.LoadPhotoFromS3(s3Region.ToString(), s3Bucket.ToString(), s3Key, logFormatter);
```

The workaround is simple enough just wondering why this might be?

Comment: Is it a compilation error or a runtime exception?

Comment: The code compiles just fine, at least as you've shown it, even without casting/converting the `dynamic` objects to `string`.  Either you have a runtime exception because one of those objects isn't actually a `string`, or the code you're trying to compile has a problem that your example code here doesn't have.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. The exception is a runtime error and the reason I'm asking the question is that I know that the s3Region, s3Bucket and s3Key values in the source dynamic object are strings. Wondering if I declare the intermediate values that hold them as 'string' instead of 'var' they will be converted automatically?

Comment: @FredStrauss If you're getting an exception , then clearly they're *not* strings, that or one of the other parameters isn't valid for the signature of the method.

Answer (score -1):

You can receive parameters as objects and then evaluate if are strings, like this example:

```
public static void LoadPhotoFromS3(object incomingS3Region, object incomingS3Bucket, object incomingS3Key, LogObject logFormatter)
{
    if (incomingS3Region.GetType() == typeof(string) && incomingS3Bucket.GetType() == typeof(string) && incomingS3Key.GetType() == typeof(string))
    {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

s3Region and s3Bucket are of type dynamic.  The method requires them to be of type string.  Since the compiler cannot guarantee the type of s3Region and s3Bucket, it cannot assume it's a string.

Comment: Yes, when using `dynamic` the method call cannot be bound statically.  It needs to be bound dynamically, which is exactly what will happen when you use `dynamic`.

Comment: we both missed a fact that [operations that contain expressions of type dynamic are not resolved or type checked by the compiler.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) so this should compile fine.

Comment: @Selman22 the only thing you missed was to say that s3region or s3bucket might not actually be strings, which would then cause a RuntimeBinderExeption with that message.